# How to serialize a list of dictionaries into json and return the response?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

```
class HelloView(ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = HelloSerializer
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    range_type = request.data['range_type'].lower()
    if range_type == "daily":
        try:
            client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
            db = client['MyDatabase'] 
            from_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(request.data['from_date'], "%Y-%m-%d")
            to_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.data['to_date'], "%Y-%m-%d")
            response_list = []
            for i in db.MyCollection.find({"date": {'$gte': from_date,
                                                              '$lte': to_date}}):
                response_list.append(i)
            return JsonResponse(response_list, safe=False)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({"status": e}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have a list of dictionaries as:

```
response_list = [
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('5c5ac3227e23080a2beac8a5'),
        'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 3, 0, 0),
        'per_service_bill': {'network': 5.234823, 'storage': 0.00355492071},
        'total_cost': 5.23837792071
    },
    {
        '_id': objectid('5c5ac32d7e23080a2beac8be'),
        'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 4, 0, 0),
        'per_service_bill': {'network': 4.9254925499999995, 'storage': 0.00351209034},
        'total_cost': 4.92900464034
    }
]
```

I've tried these (with their respective imports) but none is working:

1. return JsonResponse(response_list, safe=False)
2. json.dumps(response_list, safe = False)
3. serializers.serialize('json', response_list)

Can anyone tell what`s the fix?

I need to return the json response but it gives error as:

**"TypeError: Object of type TypeError is not JSON serializable"**

Comment: can you share the json which you are using and the code which throws this error?

Comment: response_list =[{'_id': ObjectId('5c5ac3227e23080a2beac8a5'), 'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 3, 0, 0), 'per_service_bill': {'Network': 5.234823, 'Storage': 0.00355492071}, 'total_cost': 5.23837792071}, {'_id': ObjectId('5c5ac32d7e23080a2beac8be'), 'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 4, 0, 0),'per_service_bill': {'Network': 4.9254925499999995, 'Storage': 0.00351209034}, 'total_cost': 4.92900464034}]

Comment: you need to show more of your code you are trying. Because from the error message it looks like you are trying to serialize an object of `TypeError` not a list

Comment: Can you share your related `views`? Also I tried with yours json data and return no error with `return Response(response_list, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)`

Comment: @uedemir That was the first thing i tried but that didn`t work too

Comment: class APIView(ModelViewSet):
 serializer_class = HelloSerializer
 def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)  # Create connection to MongoDB
  db = client['CESdatabase']  # DB name
  from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.data['from_date'], "%Y-%m-%d")
  to_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.data['to_date'], "%Y-%m-%d")
  response_list = []
  for i in db.registration_dailycost.find({"date": {'$gte': from_date, '$lte': to_date}}):
   response_list.append(i)
  return JsonResponse(response_list, safe=False)
@VaibhavVishal

Comment: Update your question with the `class APIView`. So that your question looks readable. Its a nightmare to me :)

Comment: can you some of ur code, what have u try

Comment: @7wick, please add your code in the body of the question, properly formatted and in code tags as shown with `response_list` above.

Comment: Problem is with this line `return Response({"status": e}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`. You are trying to serialize an error object `e`. Try replacing `e` with `str(e)`. Like this: `return Response({"status": str(e)}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`. Also in `try` block return a `Response` instead of `JsonResponse`.

Answer (score 1):

The type of ObjectId is unclear and datatime is a complex type. Json focuses on serializing dictionaries, lists, integers, floats and strings. Anything that is not in this list of types cannot be serialized. I left out the ObjectId objects and the error I got was 
    `Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable`

One solution would be to stringify your variables:

```
response_list = [
  {
    '_id': str(ObjectId('5c5ac3227e23080a2beac8a5')),
    'date': str(datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 3, 0, 0)),
    'per_service_bill': {'network': 5.234823, 'storage': 0.00355492071},
    'total_cost': 5.23837792071
  },
  {
    '_id': str(ObjectId('5c5ac32d7e23080a2beac8be')),
    'date': str(datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 4, 0, 0)),
    'per_service_bill': {'network': 4.9254925499999995, 'storage': 0.00351209034},
    'total_cost': 4.92900464034
  }
]
```

In the end you will need a dictionary or string representation of your complex objects. You may than build the correct complex object from the string/dictionary at the client side.

Comment: I will store "_id" as string in DB itself, but cannot store "date" as string. If I do so I won`t be able to perform the query I am doing here:
db.MyCollection.find({"date": {'$gte': from_date, '$lte': to_date}}):

Comment: I would guess that ObjectId is an integer, so you might want to cast it to an integer before returning the dictionary. I guess the difficulty here is that you try to return a json from a database query.